# How to apply theme like Applock app does in Android

Tags: android, locking, themes

I have one lock application and I just want to integrate theme feature like AppLock (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock) has.

If user select any theme images it will redirect to play store and install that theme app.

After that, all those theme app should not display in the menu app list, and If I uninstall the app, all theme app also uninstall with it.

All the advice are appreciated.

Thanks,